# Spark + ElasticSearch returns RDD[(String, Map[String, Any])]. How can I manipulate Any?

Tags: scala, types, elasticsearch, apache-spark

Scala 2.10.4

ElasticSearch 1.4.4

Spark 1.3

Elasticsearch-hadoop 2.1.0.Beta3

Following the [docs](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html#spark-write-dyn), I'm able to create an rdd from ES documents as follows:

```
val data sc.edRDD('indexName/type')
```

and that returns an RDD of tuples of type

```
(String, Map[String, Any])
```

where the String is the document id and the Map represents the ES document with fieldname: String -> fieldvalue: Any. But because the value type is Any, I can't do much to manipulate that data. E.g. if I want to

```
data.first()._2.get("someField")
```

The field value is, say, a double in ES, but it's Any in Spark. If I print this value it's something like

```
Buffer(61.15)
```

Trying to cast it with .asInstanceOf[Double], .toDouble, or combinations of these produces exceptions like:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JListWrapper cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

What's the correct way to manipulate data in this simple case? To make things more grim, the data I actually want lives in a nested document, which means that Any typed value in the original Map is itself a Map[String, Any] and those Any typed values are sometimes numbers and sometimes lists of tuples depending on the key.

Comment: If you happen to be storing the original `_source` with your docs then you could just take the `_source` from each Map, which will always be a String, and then parse that yourself into a real fully typed model class.  You would do this in a `map` operation taking you from `(String, Map[String,Any])` to `T` where `T` is your model class type.  Just a thought but it might work

Comment: Can I be assured that the fields in that _source String will always come in a specified (it looks to be alphabetical) order?

Comment: I have no idea about the order guarantee of those fields, but if you use a json parser, like say Jackson, it shouldn't care about the order of the fields either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is because the type being returned [is a buffer](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/scala/collection/mutable/Buffer.html) - not a Double.

If you cast it to a Buffer you will not get the class cast exception. For example, indexing the following document in ES:

```
{
    "myDouble" : 4.20,
    "myString" : "test",
    "myList" : [1.2, 93.2, 42.3]
}
```

And then querying from spark:

```
val documents = sc.esRDD("test/test", "?q=*")
val doc = documents.first()._2

println(doc.get("myDouble").get.asInstanceOf[Double]) # 4.2
println(doc.get("myString").get.asInstanceOf[String]) # test

import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer

println(doc.get("myList").get.asInstanceOf[Buffer[Double]]) 
# Buffer(1.2, 93.2, 42.3)

println(doc.get("myList").get.asInstanceOf[Buffer[Double]].mkString(","))
# 1.2,93.2,42.3
```

Comment: Really good answer. I would just add that a convenience method say getFromDoc[T](doc, key) might be useful to build here.